# sed search replace sentence with stars

Tags: sed

I need to find and replace such part of text in a text file using sed

```
**   **
```

to a word, but standard way

```
sed -i 's/**   **/textstars/g'
```

does not work, so thanks for any hint to try

Answer (score 1):

You'll just need to escape them.

```
sed -i 's/\*\*/textstars/g' file_name
```

Comment: Unfortunately - still not work. Tried `sed -i 's/\*\*   \*\*/textstars/g'` -anyway it says `sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'`, any other ideas ?

Comment: Everything is correct, I just missed some important outside this expression

Answer (score 0):

As `Ts-Mini write, you need to escape the`*`

```
echo "test **   ** more data **test**" | sed  's/\*\* *\*\*/#new data#/g'
test #new data# more data **test**
```

It replaces the first hit only, since it contains spaces between the `**`